# Write html content to Excel worksheet

Tags: c#, .net, html, excel, worksheet

Suppose I have to create a worksheet and put some `html` content into it in a loop.

```
foreach(...)
{
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.Add(
        Missing.Value, 
        Missing.Value, 
        1, 
        Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet
    );

    // write html to a worksheet

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
}
```

How do I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in an API to do this, my company has a product called DocRaptor that converts HTML to Excel format.

Here's a link to DocRaptor's home page:

[DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/)

And a link to our API documentation:

[DocRaptor API documentation](http://docraptor.com/documentation)